# C++: Reading a Text File and Storing Data to a Dynamic Memory Array

Tags: dynamic-memory-allocation

I am getting an error and I can't figure out why, below is my code:

```
// reads a file and stores data to a dynamic memory aray
string readFile(string filename, string** list, int size){
        *list = new string[size];
        ifstream file(filename);
        string line;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            getline(file, line);
            *(list + i) = line; // getting an error at this line
        }

        file.close();
        return **list;
    }
```

Comment: Its just not allowed in C++. The compiler needs to know up front how big an array needs to be. The accepted way around this is to use the `vector` class from the `stl`. Also you should use `foreach` to avoid off by one errors.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I did set the size of the array in main. I would love to use vector but storing data to a dynamic memory array is one of the requirements of the assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
*(list + i) = line; // getting an error at this line
```

Should be:

```
*(*list + i) = line; //because *(list + i) is of type string*, not string
```